# Scripting out all SQL Linked servers on all servers with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I need to export script of all my linked server in my environment to a file for each server.

The following command below successfully scripts out all the linked servers on ServerName1

```
get-childitem | %{$_.script()} >> C:\Users\someuser\Documents\Powershell\OutputFiles\ServerName1.sql
```

The issue is that I have 35 servers and in order for this command to work I need to change directories of each server.

In other words the command need to be run as follows for each server

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\ServerName1\DEFAULT\LinkedServers> get-childitem | %{$_.Script()} >> C:\Users\someuser\Documents\Powershell\OutputFiles\ServerName1.sql
```

How could I loop a command that runs from different paths based on Server Name and names the file same as the server name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Literal SQLSERVER:\SQL | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $serverName = $_.Name
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.PSPath DEFAULT\LinkedServers) |
      ForEach-Object Script > "C:\Users\someuser\Documents\Powershell\OutputFiles\$serverName.sql"
  }
```

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)  `-LiteralPath SQLSERVER:\SQL` is assumed to return items that each represent a server [THIS MAY NOT BE TRUE - SEE BELOW.]
- Each resulting item is then processed in the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block:

  - [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) is used to construct the full path to the `DEFAULT\LinkedServers` subfolder of the server item at hand, whose child items `Get-ChildItem` then enumerates and on each of which `ForEach-Object Script` invokes the `.Script()` method, using [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax).

    - That is, `ForEach-Object Script` (`% Script`) is the equivalent of `% { $_.Script() }` in your question.
- Note that `>` is enough to capture *all* output from the pipeline in the target file; `>>` is only needed if you want to *append* to a *preexisting* target file.

---

You state that `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath SQLSERVER:\SQL` does *not* list all servers, and that you want to **provide the list of server names via  a *text* file**:

- Save the list of server names to `Servers.txt`, with each name on its own line.
- Then try the following:

  - Note: The assumption is that, for a given server X, accessing path `SQLSERVER:\SQL\X\DEFAULT\LinkedServers` implicitly connects to it.

```sh
Get-Content Servers.txt | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$_\DEFAULT\LinkedServers" |
      ForEach-Object Script > "C:\Users\someuser\Documents\Powershell\OutputFiles\$_.sql"
  }
```

Comment: Getting data from file worked

Comment: Glad to hear it, @LeoTorres.